# Sorting in Access 2010 with linked table to SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2014

Tags: ms-access-2010, sql-server-express

Good day - This is the first time I post in this forum. I hope I can find the answer I am looking for.

I recently migrated my Database built in Access 2010 to Microsoft SQL Server Express 2014. I did this with a tool that I downloaded called Microsoft SQL Migration Assistant for Access. Everything was transferred fine and now I can query from Access wile data are retrieved from SQL Server.

I can retrieve data fine, however, when my query includes sorting, access returns the following error:

""""ODBC CALLED FAILED
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Server Driver]Query Timed out Expired(#0)""""

I am frustrated as I can figure out how to get around this.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thank You,

Comment: Add indexes on the fields you're sorting on.

Comment: Hello - I usually sort two fields, they are both primary keys and hence an index is automatically added. I tried to increase the time out higher than the 60 (default) it worked, but. i believe this should not be the fix. The queries are much slower than what I had everything in Access. Even my computer performance slowed down.

Comment: Your query may need some adjustments.